# How to submit form using shortcuts without clear input area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use JQuery and have a form with emails (input field and bin icon to delete an email). When I add/edit email and then use shortcuts (like ctrl+enter) everything works fine and form submits, but when I click on the bin icon to delete an email, form submits only manually (by clicking on 'Submit') and shortcuts doesn't work.

My question is — is it possible to track keydown without clear input field, e.g. when bin icon was clicked once or more?

Here's my JQuery code:

*For deleting emails:*

```
function deleteEmail() {
    const emailId = parseInt(
      $(this)
        .attr('id')
        .slice('delete_email_button'.length),
      5
    );
    $(`#emails${emailId}`).remove();
```

*For shortcuts:*

```
  $obj.find('.enter-submit').keydown(function submitForm(event) {
    if ((event.keyCode === 10 || event.keyCode === 13) && (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey)) {
      $(this)
        .closest('form')
        .find('input[type=submit]')
        .click();
    }
  });
```

Comment: It's unclear how `deleteEmail` is connected to your click logic vs your keydown logic

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I tried to shorten the code but overdid it. I have form in Rails, `deleteEmail` is in `onLoad()`. My shortcuts are in `addEnterSubmitEventListeners()` which is via another method linked in data-action attribute in a form.